# Recursive query in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Data set with parent Child tree in MongoDB. and i need details of parent with each row. I am unable to stuff the data set as below in Mongo.

Collection Structure:

[image]

Expected Output:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [$graphLookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/) to run recursive query in MongoDB. Once you get an object and all it's parents you can run [$concatArrays](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/index.html) to create one array and then use [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html) with [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html) to get multiple documents in a result set:

```
db.collection.aggregate( [
    {
        $graphLookup: {
            from: "collection",
            startWith: "$parent_org",
            connectFromField: "parent_org",
            connectToField: "_id",
            as: "hierarchy"
        }
    },
    {
        $match: {
            _id: 4
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            result: {
                $concatArrays: [ "$hierarchy", [ { _id: "$_id", "org_name": "$org_name", parent_org: "$parent_org" } ] ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $unwind: "$result"
    },
    {
        $replaceRoot: {
            newRoot: "$result"
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: {
            _id: 1
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/SilUmls8BVF)